# Comparing mean squared errors for different curves

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, least-squares, mean-square-error

I am finding the least squares fit for a linear, a quadratic and a cubic function, and am trying to print their errors. Everything works well, but I don't understand why their errors are increasing if I am getting a better fit every time, am I computing the error in a wrong way? Here are the plots, and my code follows:

[image]

[image: ][1]]

[image]

This is the code that gets me the cubed plot for example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array(((0,1),
             (1,1),
             (2,1),
             (3,1)))
xfeature = A.T[0]
squaredfeature = A.T[0] ** 2
cubedfeature = A.T[0] ** 3
ones = np.ones(4)

b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin=2 ).T
b = b.reshape(4)

order = 3

features = np.concatenate((np.vstack(ones), np.vstack(xfeature), np.vstack(squaredfeature), np.vstack(cubedfeature)), axis = 1)
xstar = np.matmul( np.matmul( np.linalg.inv( np.matmul(features.T, features) ), features.T), b)

plt.scatter(A.T[0],b, c = 'red')
u = np.linspace(0,3,1000)
plt.plot(u, u**3*xstar[3] + u**2*xstar[2] + u*xstar[1] + xstar[0], 'b-')
plt.show()

b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin=2 ).T
y_prediction = u**3*xstar[3] + u**2*xstar[2] + u*xstar[1] + xstar[0]
SSE = np.sum(np.square(y_prediction - b))
MSE = np.mean(np.square(y_prediction - b))
print("Sum of squared errors:", SSE)
print("Mean squared error:", MSE)
```

Comment: If you compute the polynomial by least squares you can compute the residual vector and the posterior variance of the solution. Moreover, LS requires redundancy, i.e., more equations than parameters to solve. The cubic polynomial should give you zero residuals as exactly 4 points

Comment: also, `numpy` has its own least squares method (`numpy.lstsq`), so you compare your results with the ones computed by that method

Comment: `y_prediction` and `b` should have the same dimension (but they don't). You are actually [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and getting an array with shape `(4, 1000)`.

Comment: @ZachiShtain what are the residuals exactly? And how do I compute them? Is there a certain formula?

Comment: @AhmadMoussa residuals are the values that you are minimizing by least squares. Actually, it is more correct to say that least squares minimized the sum of squared residuals. Basically, it is the difference between the value predicted by the estimated model to the measured one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's just a tiny mistake in your last block of code: You are computing the errors along the line instead of just for the points. Instead, what you want to do is to compute the distance for each of the points. In other words, y_prediction and b should have the same dimensions

```
b = np.array((1,2,0,3))
y_prediction = xfeature**3*xstar[3] + xfeature**2*xstar[2] + xfeature*xstar[1] + xstar[0]
SSE = np.sum(np.square(y_prediction - b))
MSE = np.mean(np.square(y_prediction - b))
print("Sum of squared errors:", SSE)
print("Mean squared error:", MSE)
```

Was that what you were after?

Comment: No, this doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, changed the first line of code, now it should look as intended. What I wanted to highlight is that both b and y_prediction should have shape (4,)

Answer (score 4):

As a different approach to the fitting, here is an example Python graphical polynomial fitter using numpy's polyfit(). You can change the polynomial order at the top of the code.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7, 0.0])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7, 0.1])

polynomialOrder = 2 # example quadratic

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, polynomialOrder)
print('Fitted Parameters:', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xData)
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: As an aside, I lived in Tokyo's Azabu-juban district in the late 1990's.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I would accept your answer if it weren't for the fact that the entire point of this exercise was to not use numpy's inbuilt functions. Upvoted nonetheless